# Printing specific lines from all documents in a folder

Tags: linux, command-prompt

I want to print all the lines that contains "testing.$" from all folder's files.

I am trying the following command, but I am getting a error. What am I missing?

> find ./* -type f -exec grep -l testing.$ {} \ | grep -n ^ | grep
> ^Linha_do_Arquivo: | cut -d: -f2;
>
> find: missing argument: '-exec'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `find` for this.
With `grep` only:

```
grep -rh "testing.$" .
```

`-h` hides the filename in the output. Omit it if you want to output it as well.

Comment: While I think Tim's answer is the closest to what is requested, if you want to omit subdirectories, you can use `grep -d skip 'testing.$' *` (note: the *single-quotes* - the question is a bit ambiguous whether you are looking for a literal `'testing.$'` or the regular expression `"testing.$"` - the two of which are very different things)